# Возможно ли перезаписать файл на сайте с правами 777?

Tags: веб-программирование

Допустим, на хостинге, в доступной из веба папке лежит файл с правами 777. Возможно ли переименовать его или перезаписать его содержимое "из вне" сайта (т.е. например, скриптом запущенным на другом сайте)? И если вдруг можно, то можно сразу с примером кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если осуществлять доступ через web-server (apache и т.д ) То ответ - НЕТ.
Апач производит только операции чтения файлов. А вот скрипты, повешенные на этот домен вполне могут его изменить.

Т.е если есть возможность испольнять код на сервере - то файл изменить можно, если нет - то нет.